# Count number of retweeted tweets and total number tweets have been retweeted

Tags: mysql

Consider the following tables

```
users                                tweets
---------------------------------    ---------------------------
user_id num_retweets sum_retweets    tweet_id user_id retweeted
---------------------------------    ---------------------------
1                                    1        1       3
2                                    2        1       0
3                                    3        1       4
                                     4        2       0
                                     5        2       0
                                     6        3       1
                                     7        3       2
                                     8        3       0
```

I want to count `num_retweets`: the number of times a users has written a retweet that has been retweeted and `sum_retweets`: the number of times all of a users tweets have been retweeted. The expected `users` table after the `UPDATE` query is:

```
users
---------------------------------
user_id num_retweets sum_retweets
---------------------------------
1       2            7 <-- 3 + 4
2       0            0
3       2            3 <-- 1 + 2
```

Any help on building these two queries would be greatly appreaciated :-) I keep having trouble performing `UPDATE`s across tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE
USERS u
JOIN (
SELECT 
    tweets.user_id,
    COUNT(IF(tweets.retweeted > 0, 1, null)) as num_retweets,
    SUM(tweets.retweeted) as sum_retweets
FROM tweets
GROUP BY tweets.user_id
) as t ON t.user_id = u.user_id
SET u.num_retweets = t.num_retweets, u.sum_retweets = t.sum_retweets
```